# IMPORTHTML returns N/A after a while, is there a workaround?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In a spreadsheet, I have a Mastersheet with :
A1 : name
B1 : link

When a new name comes in, it automatically creates a new sheet with :
A1 : name
B1 : link
C1 : importhtml formula that imports a table

It works everytime but after a certain time, it returns N/A. The only way i found to reload the table is to go to my Mastersheet, copy the column with all the links, delete it and paste it again. Then every sheet reloads the table and works fine again.

Does someone have a solution to this ?

Comment: The issue is not reproducible. Could you share a sample sheet?

Comment: As said under the answer, "functions cease to work after a while in an almost unpredictable fashion". I can't reproduce it then..

Answer (score 0):

All of the =IMPORT... functions cease to work after a while in an almost unpredictable fashion. You should make a habit of putting all your source links in a single sheet in column A and in column B reference column A if a checkbox is true otherwise return blank. Then you use the checkbox to toggle all of your source links. (check and uncheck to force reload) with importhtml specifically though the google ip that is being used can be banned or throttled by the website.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The problem is I want it to run with no manual intervention at all. Or maybe I didn't get your solution :/

Comment: @BastienSoret Once all of your links are indirectly connected to that single checkbox you could always run a macro to check and uncheck the box at certain intervals or conditions.

Comment: Okay I'll try it out, thanks ! I'll keep you posted :)